# L = [lambda x: x*i for i in range(3)] doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I started learning python 3.3 lately, and I'm currently playing with the different features. I tried the following:

```
L = [lambda x: x*i for i in range(3)]
```

And I expected it to return a list of 3 functions - the first one gets a number and returns 0, the second one gets a number and returns the same number itself, and third one gets a number x and returns 2x. Apparently all the functions in the list L returns 2x:

```
>>>L[0](4)
8
>>>L[1](-7)
-14
>>>L[2](3)
6
```

What am I missing?  How is it different from:

```
L = [lambda x: x*0, lambda x: x*1, lambda x: x*2]
```

which works as expected?

Comment: This is because of different scopes. In first case when you call any of the functions it reads `i` at the moment of calling which already is `2` no matter which function you call, i.e. inner `i` equals to the outer `i`.

Comment: It's just returning `i * 2` for the numbers you're inputting

Comment: @user2357112's target is good. Another highly related (almost dupe post) is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions