# Why is this simple lambda function giving bizarre outputs?

Tags: python, lambda

I am learning lambdas in Python. I need to create a list of functions `f = [f1, f2...]` such that each function `fi(x)` takes in a list `x` and returns `(x[i]-1)`.

This is how I tried coding it, but I am getting surprising results. Please help me understand why each of the three prints give different results. The last two have left me absolutely stumped!

```
f = [(lambda x: x[i]-1) for i in range(5)]
# I expect f to be [ (lambda x: x[0]-1), (lambda x: x[1]-1), ...]

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print f[0](x), f[1](x), f[2](x)    # output: 4 4 4 !!
print [f[i](x) for i in range(5)]  # output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] as expected
print [f[k](x) for k in range(5)]  # output: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4] wha?!!!
```

Edit: This question is quite different from the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions). In the linked question there was a simple error where the user created a list of functions, instead of function-calls. However the answer by [Tomasz Gandor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021333/448474) discusses the same issue as asked here using several examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you coding something so .. weird? Pure academic interest? After all, Guido regrets having implemented them: http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf

Comment: well in Python 3 it doesn't work with `i` either...

Comment: The only regrettable thing about Python lambdas is that they're not implemented *better*.

Comment: @Arne Recknagel: An optimization method (scipy.cobyla) requires constraints to be specified as a list of functions, one for each dimension. I need to convert from simple bounds to constraints, leaving the number of dimensions a variable.

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar Fair enough. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a common gotcha. What you're looking for is

```
f = [(lambda x, i=i: x[i]-1) for i in range(5)]
z = [1,2,3,4,5]
print f[0](z),f[1](z),f[2](z)
0 1 2
```

Your list comprehension creates 5 functions, which all points to `i`. At the end of the loop, `i` equals 4. Hence no matter what lambda you call, it evalutes `i` as 4.

You want to *assign the current value of i, to the local variable of the lambda function*. You do this with *optional arguments*.

Lambda evalutes params on runtime. Python will allow you to define something such this, it might shed some more light:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x[i] - 1
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> f(l)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#91>", line 1, in <module>
    f(l)
  File "<pyshell#89>", line 1, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: x[i] - 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

***Update***: replying to questions from comments, this example is less related to the original question but helps to better understand how function params evaluation happens

```
myvar=1

def f(myvar=myvar):
    print myvar

f()  # prints 1
f(2) # prints 2
myvar = 5
f()  # prints 1
```

If you don't declare `myvar` before declaring `f`, you would get `NameError: name 'myvar' is not defined`. This because function variables evaluted on 'compile' time. Lambda's evalutes on *runtime*, but when we provide optional arguments - it happens immediately (hence i=i). Hope it provides more clarity on the subject :)

Comment: Just to clarify, wouldn't it be a better idea to define the index with a different name in order to avoid giving a parameter the same name as its value? E.g.: `f = [(lambda x, idx=i: x[idx]-1) for i in range(5)]`

Comment: Python's scoping rules are not intuitive to me (coming from a C/C++ background). In my example, I had assumed that the scope of i was limited to the first line.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel it's a matter of choice, since you don't address it anymore in your code besides your lambda definition - both options are clear enough.

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar it's not a matter of scoping, but how lambda's work. See my snippet how lambda is evaluted at runtime, and not at declaration :-)

Comment: @Vinny I assumed that it behaves exactly as a function head. Say, `my_var = 1; def my_func(my_var=my_var): print(my_var) # prints '1'` , the assignment of the parameter to the value is completely valid, but I would avoid giving them the same name, simply to avoid the confusion of an, intuitively, nonsensical line. Am I wrong in understanding how lambdas work?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel functions evalute signature parameters on definition. Your understanding is correct, but if you change the value of `my_var` afterwards your function would keep printing the original value. Why is that? because you assigned the value of `my_var` when python interpreted your `def` line. I've updated my answer with an example of how it is interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `i` is in global scope and is still `4` when you call any of the functions. If you do `i = 1` then your two anomalous outputs will become `1 1 1` and `[1 1 1 1 1]`

I found this works:

```
g = lambda i: lambda x: x[i] - 1
f = [ g(i) for i in range(5) ]  # i missed here
print [f[k]([1,2,3,4,5]) for k in range(5)] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The `i` is now scoped to a second lambda.