# How to convert a list of values to a list of functions that return these values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert a list of return values to a list of functions that return these values.

```
lst = [1, 2]
funcs = [lambda: x for x in lst]
```

this is equivalent to:

```
x = 2
funcs = [lambda: x, lambda: x]
```

but I am trying to get:

```
funcs = [lambda: 1, lambda 2]
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions) explains why this is happening, but doesn't provide a way to do it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
[lambda x=x: x for x in lst]
```

Explanation: This creates a new function parameter `x` which gets initialized with the default value currently set to the loop parameter `x`. When you call the method without parameters, the default will be returned.

I suggest to use different names to make it less confusing:

```
[lambda result=i: result for i in lst]
```

Another approach is to write your own `lambda`-like function which defines nested functions that it returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
def f(x):
    return lambda: x

funcs = [f(x) for x in lst]
```

This approach might in particular be useful if the functions are more complicated, because here you can put an arbitrary function definition into the body of `f`.