# How to get the unique elements of the first column of a text file?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am processing a text file whose columns are separated by tabs .I want to get all the unique values of the first column.

Text Input e.g:

```
"a\t\xxx\t..\zzz\n
 a\t\xxx\t....\n
 b\t\xxx\t.....\n
 b\t\xxx\t.....\n
 c\t\xxx\t.....\n"
```

So in this case i would like to get an array: `uniques=["a","b","c"]`

**Code:**

```
def getData(fin):
    input = open(fin, 'r',encoding='utf-16')
    headers=input.readline().split()
    lines=input.readlines()[1:]
    uniques=[(lambda line: itertools.takewhile(lambda char: char!='\t',line))for line in lines]
```

Instead of the desired values i get a list of :

```
<function getData.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000000000C46DB70>
```

I have already read this article [Python: Lambda function in List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions)  and  I unserstood that you have to use parenthesis to ensure the right execution order.Still i get the same result.

Comment: IMO, not a good idea to write such a complicated thing in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for unique elements `set()` is a good solution:

```
def getData(fin):
    with open(fin, 'r') as input:
    first_cols = list(set([line.split("\\")[0] for line in input.readlines()]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `split()`:

```
def getData(fin):
    input = open(fin, 'r',encoding='utf-16')
    headers=input.readline().split()
    lines=input.readlines()[1:]
    uniques=[line.split('\t')[0] for line in lines]
```

Note that this will not produce unique values, it will produce every line's value. To make this unique, do:

```
uniques = list(set(uniques))
```

Answer (score 2):

May be [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) can simplify your problem:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open(fin, 'rb') as csvfile:
...      spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
...      list(set( row[0] for row in spamreader ))
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: By the way, in python 2.7, may be you will need [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
s = """
   a\txxx\t..\zzz\n
   a\txxx\t....\n
   b\txxx\t.....\n
   b\txxx\t.....\n
   c\txxx\t.....\n"
   """
new_data = re.findall('(?<=\n\s\s\s)[a-zA-Z]', s)
uniques = [a for i, a in enumerate(new_data) if a not in new_data[:i]]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I know thank you for pointing me out but i felt comfortable with lambda constructs in other languages so  i thought it should be similar here too.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
lines=input.readlines()[1:]         # reads all lines after the header 
                                    # you read already and skips the 1st one

uniques = list(set(x.split('\t')[0] for x in lines))
```

Caveat: This might reorder your uniques

Comment: It is `list(set( x.split('\t')[0] for x in lines)) `, without the braked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer indeed it works as a charm ,i was interested in the itertools since i believe you can manipulate data generically with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Try Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
uniques = df[df.columns[0]].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension needs to start with an expression rather than a lambda. Currently your code just creates a list of lambdas (note that the outermost parentheses enclose a lambda, not an expression). You could fix it like this:

```
def getData(fin):
    input = open(fin, 'r',encoding='utf-16')
    headers=input.readline().split()
    lines=input.readlines()[1:]
    uniques=[itertools.takewhile(lambda char: char!='\t',line) for line in lines]
```

There are still a couple of bugs in this code: (1) by the time you get to readlines(), the first row will already have been removed from the input buffer, so you should probably drop the `[1:]`. (2) your `uniques` variable will have all the entries from the first column, including duplicates.

You could fix these bugs and streamline the code a little more like this:

```
with open(fin, 'r',encoding='utf-16') as input:
    headers=input.next().split('\t')
    uniques = set(line.split('\t')[0] for line in input)
    uniques = list(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter then try this approach,

Open the file and then just split the words and as you said first column is always what you want to just take what you need and leave the remaining content.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    print(set([list(line)[0] for line in f]))
```

output:

```
{'b', 'a', 'c'}
```