# Why lambda function is not applicable in case of list comprehension, whereas some other user defined function works in the list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have changed my question a bit, I think my question was not clear before. Apologies!!!

I have mentioned two cases below: one with lambda function and the other with a user defined function.

Case 1: Using a lambda function.

```
[lambda i: i*2  for i in range(4) ]
```

The output is the list of 4 same functions as given below:

```
[<function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>(i)>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>(i)>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>(i)>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>(i)>]
```

Case 2: Using a user defined function

```
def func(x):
   return(x*2)

[func(i)  for i in range(4) ]
```

The output here is as intended.

```
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. You're not *calling* the lambda in the list comprehensions, so you build a list *of lambdas*.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here - the expression with `lambda:` is a function, so if you create four of them with your comprehension, you get four functions in a list; if you apply it to a column, it gets applied. If you want to do the calculation in the comprehension, `[i*2 for i in range(4)]` will work.

Comment: Case 1 and 2 are identical substitute regardless of "i" or "x" used. This has nothing to do with pandas or data-science. At case 3 you start something but did not finish it properly. Include a descent example if you want to talk about theory.

Comment: Does `[(lamvda .,,)(x) for x ...]` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Lambda function in List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions)

Comment: `your lambda function doesn’t call the function. Is creating 4 different lambda functions, as you see on your output, and put all those in a list  `

Comment: `[(lambda i: i*2)(i) for i in range(4)]` is how should work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your difference is because

```
lambda i: i*2
```

is a function *definition*, not a function *call*. To see this, do

```
func = lambda i: i*2 
print(func)
```

So your list comprehension is defining 4 identical functions. But you want to define *one* function  and call it 4 times. This will work:

```
[(lambda x: x*2)(i)  for i in range(4) ]
```

Compare that with:

```
[func(i)  for i in range(4) ]
```

and you will see that `(lambda x: x*2)` is the equivalent of `func`. The identifier `func` is the *name* of a function that you have defined before, and `(lambda x: x*2)` is an *expression* that defines the function in-line.

Here `x` is the parameter to the lambda function (just as it is in `func`) and `i` is the value you are calling that function with.

But that is a very complicated way to to things. Defining a lambda function made it hard for you to see what was wrong, and hard for others to see what your intent was.