# How to make a persistent value from variable in a lambda function

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of properties and their limiting values. For properties containing 'max', the limiting values is the maximum allowed. Similarly for minima.

I'm trying to create a dictionary of functions. Each function will check an input value against the limiting value for a property of the list.

```
limits = {'variable1 max': 100,
          'variable1 min': 10}

check_acceptable = {key: (lambda x: x < lim) if 'max' in key else 
                         (lambda x: x > lim) 
                    for key, lim in limits.items()}

# Now, I'd expect this to be True, since 90 < 100:
check_acceptable['variable1 max'](90)

Out: False
```

What happended here is that the lambda function got assigned the variable `lim`, and in the for loop, `lim` last value was 10, then my first lambda function is wrong.

How do I fix that?

--- edit - adding a more generic example of the same behaviour:

```
funcs = []
for i in range(5):
    funcs.append(lambda _: i)

for j in range(5):
    print(funcs[j](j), end='')

# Expected: 01234
Out: 44444
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue - The variable `lim` is not "stored" in the lambda, so both lambdas compare the argument with `10`.

Possible solution:

```
import functools
def a_less_than_b(a,b):
  return a < b

def a_greater_than_b(a,b):
  return a > b

limits = {'variable1 max': 100,
          'variable1 min': 10}

check_acceptable = {key: functools.partial(a_less_than_b, b=lim) if 'max' in key else 
                         functools.partial(a_greater_than_b, b=lim)
                    for key, lim in limits.items()}

# Now, I'd expect this to be True, since 90 < 100:
check_acceptable['variable1 max'](90)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that each `lambda` inside the dict comprehension is capturing only the last version of `lim` it finds, as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions). We can get around this limitation by doing some [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) on the `lim` parameter:

```
limits = {'variable1 max': 100,
          'variable1 min': 10}

check_acceptable = {key: (lambda lim: (lambda x: x < lim))(lim) if 'max' in key else
                         (lambda lim: (lambda x: x > lim))(lim)
                    for key, lim in limits.items()}
```

The above will allow each `lambda` to capture each one of the arguments it encounters; it works as expected:

```
check_acceptable['variable1 max'](90)
=> True
```

Comment: @Raf To pretty it up, use named functions instead of lambdas. This has the added benefit of being able to debug the code more easily since it won't be all jammed on a single line.